# Maven not using the local repo

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm using maven without m2e, my mvn install is failing because a plugin is not available anymore on maven central.
I'm working with an old pom.xml dating from 2008 and must uses maven-cdk-plugin version 3.3.3.Final.

Since it was not available anymore I took it on someone else computer and putted it in my .m2 local repo.
.m2\org\richfaces\cdk\maven-cdk-plugin\3.3.3.Final

however I'm still getting this error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.richfaces.cdk:maven-cdk-plugin:3.3.3.Final or one of its depe
ndencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.richf
aces.cdk:maven-cdk-plugin:jar:3.3.3.Final: Failure to find org.richfaces.cdk:mav
en-cdk-plugin:pom:3.3.3.Final in http://uk.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the lo
cal repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
UK has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Why would he want to check maven2, it's inside my local repo? D:

thanks

Comment: first things first, did you check your settings.xml for where it is pointing to, for the local repository, it should default to ${user.home}/.m2/repository/. but wouldn't hurt to check

Comment: If this is a plugin you are trying to install it should be going to $MAVEN_HOME/plugins, not your .m2 folder.

Comment: my local repo is in <c:\.m2> because I have some project with A LOT of dependancy thus I had to lessen the paths size.

@perception, are you sure? maven is trying to put them in the local repo itself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must install that jar with [install plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=[jar] -DgroupId=org.richfaces.cdk \
-DartifactId=maven-cdk-plugin -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar
```

Maven will keep the structure and generate the things it needs.

Try `mvn clean install -o` to not look in internet for dependencies.

Also `echo $M2_REPO`. it should point to the .m2.

Comment: still getting the same error, the plugin was placed where I had already placed it myself

Comment: allright, I erased the content of my .m2 and used your installation command, now it's working!
Thanks

Comment: You can run 
`mvn clean install -oU` to _'download'_ again dependencies for the project using offline mode.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing is that what you mentioned the maven-cdk-plugin has never been on Maven Central cause it's available via richfaces repository so you have to configure to use the richfaces repository as well. This results in using a repository manager like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org) or [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) (alphabetical order). So you need to configure to use the richfaces repository.

See here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenRepository how to do so.

Here you can see that the plugin exists in this repository https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/

One very important thing. Any artifact which is in Maven Central will never be deleted afterwards cause otherwise this **would break builds all over the world**.

Comment: I did add the Jboss repository to my pom.xml (all of them) and my setting.xml but it did not changed anything, it still did this error.

    <repository>
      <id>Jboss</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using m2e, first you have to check Maven user settings(Window->Preference->Maven->User Settings)
In that you have first empty the input field of Global Settings.
Then in User Settings you have to map the Settings.xml file like C:\Users\o3355.m2\Settings.xml.
Lastly, you have to map the local Repository folder location in  local Repository input field like : C:\Users\o3355.m2\repository
then try to build the project.

[image: Kindly, find the image for more clear view]