# proxy repository is blocked

Tags: maven, nexus

I added a proxy repository in nexus. When I `update now` in `Routing`, it failed. The repo url I added is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo
[image]

[image]

I can access this url

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo/org/unidal/maven/plugins/codegen/2.3.2/codegen-2.3.2.pom

I can't access this url

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo

response 400: Invalid request

---

So. It's the repo server block nexus from update.

**If I don't use mirror in maven setting, Maven update will work right.**

Meanwhile, when I use nexus public repositores group as my mirror(I also added proxy repo to public repositories group), It just report `Failure to find org.unidal.maven.plugins:codegen-maven-plugin:jar:2.3.2
in http://172.xxx/nexus/content/groups/public`

How can I solve this problem?

And I guess the maven resolve flow is like:

1. maven resolve a dependency
2. find the dependency in local
3. find in repo manager
4. find in proxy repo.

As the full url like https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo/org/unidal/maven/plugins/codegen/2.3.2/codegen-2.3.2.pom can be access, repo manager could fetch the specific pom url, if my guess is right.

I wonder: Unlike [maven central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/),which you can access its index or called file tree,  this `cat.repo` you can only access its file but not its directory. So what's the diffenrence in maven? How to handle this?

---

**EDIT**

Because I've successed update not using `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>`. My local repository already download these missing plugins in Nexus. So I follow the tips in [Maven not using the local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755955/maven-not-using-the-local-repo), and that missing plugin does not cause error again, but another artifact not found in nexus again.

I also do as [maven missing artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615585/maven-missing-artifact) shows, by

> Deleting maven-metadata*.xml and _*.repositories inside local

Still not working.

Comment: Are you sure the entries on the configuration tab above are correct?

Comment: @hack_on I think it's right. I've added other proxy repo with no problem. And I add a sceenshot int the post.

Comment: I guess I was asking in case the connection from the "proxy repository" to the external repo was going through a corporate proxy that required settings like username/pass and this is why the proxy repo reports that it is blocked?

Comment: But I can access the pom url as I said in the post. So it's not an authentication problem. Thank you for giving advice.

Comment: I may be confused, but it seems the remote repo is giving this status!  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo/org/unidal/maven/plugins/codegen/2.3.2/codegen-2.3.2.jar works but https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dianping/cat/mvn-repo/org/unidal/maven/plugins/codegen/2.3.2/ gives 400

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The remote is returning HTTP code 400 (invalid request) for request to "/".

Nexus does HEAD and GET requests to the root URL to determine if the remote is reachable, and in good health.  This response code is causing Nexus to think the remote is not working.

To work around this, go to the proxy repository's configuration tab and set "auto-blocking enabled" to "false".

Comment: Thank you very much. It does help in something. After setting that the repository status change from `In Service - Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable` To `In Service`. But maven still `Failure to find`;

Comment: Yes. It works. Great. It need to be add to public group again after change the proxy setting. I just forgot.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get this failure if you are doing an `http` request to a server that only allows `https`.